# Lua bit library

Tags: lua, bit

Right now I have made my own funcs to do bitwise and + not but then I saw the bit library and tried to use it but it doesn't work how I imagined, it returns a large decimal instead of the binary bit and so my question is actually a few.

First: how to do bitwise AND on binary number using the bit32 library.

```
10110111
11000100 = 10000100
```

Second: How to calculate the ipv4 broadcast address by adding the network address and the wildcard mask in binary form using the bit32 library

```
192.168.1.0 + 31 = 192.168.1.31

11000000.10100000.00000001.00000000
00000000.00000000.00000000.00011111 = 11000000.10100000.00000001.00011111
```

Comment: You don't have an example of your code, so we can't understand what your problem is. Add a code example.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your bitwise and / not functions take string arguments.

Numbers can be represented in multiple ways.
The number 110101, which is in base two, has the same value as 53, which is in base 10.

When you say

```
x=123
```

Lua converts 123 into its binary representation, 1111011, which it then stores in memory as bits.
When you say

```
print(x)
```

Lua goes into memory, grabs x, which is 1111011, and then converts it into its more human-readable base 10 representation, and you see

```
123
```

The bitwise functions you wrote performs bit operations on strings which display the binary representation of a number like "1111011". the bit32 library performs bit operations on numbers, which display the decimal representation of a number like 123.

In Lua, "1001001" is a string, but if arithmatic operations are performed on it, it treats it as if it were a number written in base 10. So when you do

```
bit32.band("101","110")
```

the bit32.band function interprets its arguments as one-hundred-one and one-hundred-ten.

You must first convert your binary strings into numbers:

```
bit32.band(tonumber("101",2), tonumber("110",2))
```

Comment: actually no, my funcs use the number and only starts with a string and then uses tonumber(dec,2) to convert that to binary although this still doesn't answer my question.